# Trying to open a file dialog, where is comdlg32.lib?

Tags: c++, winapi

Running [this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-common-dialog-boxes#opening-a-file) in Code::Blocks 20.03, [got a](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/47adcbad-4362-4912-b0b7-03fc31a8ae79/why-cant-i-successfully-link-to-comctl32lib?forum=vclanguage) `#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")` in my header, [no joy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751685/using-getopenfilename-in-dev-c-vs). I know I need to add it to the linker, [as done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049844/adding-linker-options-to-codeblocks), but WHERE is the `comctl32.lib` file?

**Edit**: fixed the Pragma, but the problem still happens.

Comment: These are standard windows libraries in the windows api. For me the file exists here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\um` in the x64, x86, arm and arm64 folders.

Comment: Followed that path, `10.0.10240.0\`, no `um` folder, only `ucrt`. In there are the processors, with files `libucrt.lib`, `'libucrtd.lib', `ucrt.lib`, and `ucrtd.lib`, across each one.

Comment: I am have these installed because I use Visual Studio 2019 community. I assume you need to download and install the windows SDK or maybe there is some mingw setup. I don't really use that.

Comment: There are a lot of links here. Could you make the question self-contained so it's useful for other/future visitors, please?

Comment: CodeBlocks implies you're using MinGW rather than MSVC? Then those `#pragma`s are of no use, instead you need to change the linker settings. Also you need `lib??.a`, not `??.lib`. The `-lcomdlg32` flag should just work out of the box. At least it does for me on MSYS2.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You beautiful genius, that solved it! Well, it compiles now, time to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Your `#pragma` is specifying the wrong filename.  `GetOpenFileName()` is implemented in `comdlg32.dll`, not in `comctl32.dll`.  The correct lib filename you need to use is `comdlg32.lib`.  This is stated as much in the [function's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamew):

[image]

Once you correct that, if you still get the same error, then you likely don't have the Windows SDK installed for your compiler, or you don't have your compiler's search paths setup properly to find the SDK files.

Comment: Windows SDK: Which one? I'm coding on 8.1, but want to use some deprecated stuff for reverse compatibility. Will the [Win10](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/) one work?

Comment: In this particular case, it doesn't matter, since `GetOpenFileName()` has been around for over 20 years, so it will be available in all versions of the SDK. Miccrosoft does not remove deprecated APIs

Comment: @KelsonRumak Please don't modify/update the question in such a way that invalidates the answers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Cool, will get the new one

Comment: @Asteroids Got it, so just a comment about fixing it next time. Should I undo the edit?

Comment: @KelsonRumak I have undone the edit for you (which BTW, your "fix" was still wrong anyway - you link to `.lib` files, not to `.dll` files directly).

Comment: @RemyLebeau [Not necessarily with GCC on Win](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40751772/4386278)